# Project Euler #6 in Ruby (What's the difference?)

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math

I solved #6 for Project Euler using two different methods, but the second one just happened to be coincidental. I don't really understand why I don't have to return the square of new_sum like I did for my first method. Does anyone know what's the major difference between the two?

```
def square_difference(num)
  new_sum = 0
  sum = 0
  while num >= 1
    sum += num**2 && new_sum += num
    num -= 1
  end
  return new_sum**2 - sum
end
```

AND

```
def square_difference(num)
  new_sum = 0
  sum = 0
  while num >= 1
    new_sum += num && sum += num**2  
    num -= 1
  end
  return new_sum - sum
end
```

Comment: I expect the downvotes and vote to close are because your haven't told readers what "#6 for Project Euler" is.  I suggest you edit and explain in words what the problem is. It would be helpful to also give a simple numerical example with the expected output.  Once the reader understands what you are trying to accomplish, it should be fairly straightforward to analyze the two methods you have presented.

Comment: You could also calculate as follows: `num = 5; sum, sum_sq = (1..num).reduce ([0,0]) { | (sum, sum_sq), n| [sum+n, sum_sq+n*n] }; sum*sum - sum_sq #=> 170`.

Answer (score 2):

The precedence of `&&` is higher than that of `+=`. So these expressions:

```
sum += num**2 && new_sum += num

new_sum += num && sum += num**2
```

don't work as you expected. The first one just *happen* to provide the seemingly "correct" result.

Divide them into separate lines and you'll see the difference. Or, at least use `and` instead of `&&`. `and` has a lower precedence than that of `+=`.

Comment: Good catch. The last lines differ as well, though that might be a typo.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I solved [Project Euler #6](https://projecteuler.net/problem=6) before :) The second method has `new_sum` with the same value as `new_sum**2` in the first method, that's why the OP is confusing, so the last line is probably not a typo.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The correct result of `square_difference(10)` is `2640` from the problem description. With OP's code, both methods seem to have the same correct result. The OP thinks the body of both methods should have the same instructions, except the return value. That's where the confusion comes from, why the second method gives the correct result while it doesn't return `new_sum**2 - sum` as the first one does? So I'm tell the OP that the two methods don't have the same instructions because of the precedence of `&&`. Separating the statements is the way of showing how the code should work.

Comment: Sorry for the diversion. I didn't read the question carefully enough. (A bad habit of mine.) I was merely pointing out that, in addition to correcting the precedence problem, the OP needs to correct the last line of #2, but I guess that's obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Both formulas have the same subtle bug. I stepped through it a couple of times to understand what was going on.

From the second one:

```
[30] pry(main)> square_difference(4)
new_sum: 16, sum: 16, num: 3
new_sum: 41, sum: 25, num: 2
new_sum: 70, sum: 29, num: 1
new_sum: 100, sum: 30, num: 0
=> 70
```

We can see that `new_sum` does not seem to be behaving as intended.

What is actually happening is that `new_sum += num && sum += num**2` is being evaluated to `new_sum += (num && sum += num **2)`, which in turn evaluates to `new_sum += (sum += num **2)`

This is a result of the `&&` operator, which has higher precedence (as Yu Hao pointed out) and returns the first value which determines whether the AND condition is satisfied.

```
[31] pry(main)> 2 && 2
=> 2
[32] pry(main)> 2 && 4
=> 4
[33] pry(main)> 4 && 2
=> 2
[34] pry(main)> nil && 2
=> nil
[35] pry(main)> 2 && nil
=> nil
```